# Error from BoundedDiagram

Tags: computational-geometry

I cannot understand the meaning of the error

> BoundedDiagram::notuniq: BoundedDiagram requires that boundary vertices lie in unique Voronoi polygons. >>
>
> BoundedDiagram::nobd: Bounded diagram failed. >>

When I try to run the following code, it gives me the above error.

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
Boundary = {{-2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, -2}, {-2, -2}};
points = {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};
BoundedDiagram[Boundary, points]
DiagramPlot[points]
```

Is it a problem with the code? Have i misunderstood `BoundedDiagram`?

What I have posted here is a simplified situation. I am using more points in real work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you don't have enough points to use `BoundedDiagram`. The Voronoi diagram for your points looks like this

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
bounds = {{-2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, -2}, {-2, -2}};
points = {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};
DiagramPlot[points, Frame -> True]
```

[image: voronoi.1.png]

Since there are only three Voronoi regions, at least two points from your boundary set must lie in one region and this is not permitted.

If the point set is expanded to four points,

```
pts = {{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};
DiagramPlot[pts, Frame -> True]
```

then the Voronoi diagram will look like this

[image: voronoi.2.png]

Now each point in the boundary set is isolated into a unique Voronoi region, and `BoundedDiagram` will work

```
DiagramPlot[First @ BoundedDiagram[bounds, pts],
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[pts]},
  Frame -> True]
```

[image: bounded.voronoi.png]

Comment: Could you explain "Since there are only three Voronoi regions, at least two points from your boundary set must lie in one region and this is not permitted." a little further, please.